# How to keep the colors pallete same inside the surface using gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a graph, attach is fig(1) with the lc palette, It is working well. However, when I am setting a box outside it, it changes all color to red only.
How can I draw shapes outside the plot so that plot does not change its colors?

Note: I have to draw different shapes depending on crystal shapes not only a cube.
I have a data file (data.dat) that has 4 columns and a second file(plot.dat) which has three columns(positions only)
i am using the following command
splot "data.dat" u 5:6:7:4 with l lw 4 lc palette notitle, "plot.dat" u 1:2:3 w l

[![fig:1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnxQJ.png)]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28bUf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full range of colors `cbrange` in the palette is mapped to some particular range of z-values.  By default it gets the same range as the z-values used in the plot.  So in your first figure you can see that both the z values of the plot and the color values of the palette run from -0.6 to +0.6. Your plot command `splot "data.dat" u 5:6:7:4 with l lw 4 lc palette` takes a value from column 4, let's say 0, and looks up in the palette range what color that maps to.  Since 0 is right in the middle of the `cbrange`, it gets assigned the midpoint color.  In other words, the tic labels on the color bar tell you what range of colors will be used to map values taken from column 4. Apparently all of your column 4 values are near zero, since they all come out roughly the same color.

In your second plot you must have taken z coordinates from a different place.  Whatever it was, it is now being used to set different default limits to the range of palette colors `cbrange`. You can see that instead of [-0.6 : 0.6] the range has become [-0.05 : 0.01].  If you want to instead keep the same range of color values as your first plot, all you have to do is set that range explicitly rather than letting the program change it to match a new set of z values:

```
  set cbrange [-0.6 : 0.6]
```

Typically if you are plotting a bunch of different data sets and want a consistent coloring, you would choose the `cbrange` in advance and set it to that for all the plots.

Comment: Hi Ethan Thanks for your reply,  setting cbrange is still changing my surface plot in one color, though problem is solved when I am giving commands **set arrow from points** mentioned in plot.dat.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. There is no such command "set arrow from points".  Could you show sample data and the specific commands you used to plot it?

Comment: plot.dat file contains x y z coordinates information like 0.5,0.5,0.5 and 0.5,0.5-0.5, I am plotting them with lines, it is constructing a box around the plot, turning the plot in one color. However when i am using command  set arrow nohead from 0.5,0.5,o.5 to 0.5,0.5 -0.5 , set arrow nohead from 0.5,-0.5,0.5 to 0.5,-0.5,0.5 . it is also making a box around the plot but without changing the cbrange and color of the inner plot.

Comment: It's so helpful Ethan when you gave your useful comments under our questions. I am really thankful to you for taking your time out answering our problem.

Comment: If you leave the "autoscaling" active on z, which is the default, it will be set to a range large enough to include all the data or functions in the `plot` or `splot` command.  It does not, however, look at all the objects, arrows, labels, etc that you can define but are not mentioned in the actual plot command.   Regardless, the basic point is that the mapping of colors onto z values is controlled by `set cbrange`.

Comment: Hi Ethan, can I ask a quick question under this comment, though it is not directly relevant to the title of the question? I want to make a plot on this box at the corner, I was able to make the graph after using the 'set origin' and 'set size' command, but I want the new graph opaque since these lines are visible in the next graph as well. how can i make it opaque?

Comment: Since you know the origin and size, you can use that information to define an opaque rectangle `set obj 1 rectangle from screen orig_x,orig_y to screen orig_x+size_x, orig_y + size_y;` `set obj 1 behind fillstyle solid 1.0 fillcolor background`.